# Need sum of columns in array form

Tags: excel, excel-formula

From a formula I got a result {9,16;4,4;1,1}(this is after selecting and pressing F9). Now I need to get the sum but in the following form {25;8;2}. Using sum gives just one number 35. Can this be done and if yes then how?

I know this can be done using VBA, but I need to implement in base excel.

Any help is useful, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work:

```
=MMULT(<YourArray>,{1;1}))
```

Comment: Thanks, was not aware of MMULT.

Comment: @Shady, if it worked and your question is answered maybe consider to confirm as such by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Right, mystery solved thanks to you: `{9\16;4\4;1\1};{1;1}` is what I needed @ScottCraner